# Плагин WP Rocket на Wordpress, функция Delay JavaScript execution, как найти скрипт откладывающий загрузку изображения?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

имеется плагин с функцией задержки выполнения Java Scripts, из за него изображение на странице не прогрузится пока пользователь не сделает какое-либо действие (клик, движение мышкой/по сенсору и т.д), нужно, чтобы изображение загружалось в любом случае. Не могу найти скрипт отвечающий за это дело, чтобы добавить его в исключения, может кто подскажет как это сделать? плагин WP Rocket на Wordpress, функция Delay JavaScript execution